LangChain error: Must write to at least one of []
I am learning to use LangChain and I want to make a RAG agent with memory. The code I have so far is this:
### LLM
local_llm = 'llama3.2:3b-instruct-fp16'
llm = ChatOllama(model=local_llm, temperature=0)

# load PDF files from a directory
loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader("/home/carlos/Documents/LLMs/llama_agents/phone_data/")
data = loader.load()
# print the loaded data, which is a list of tuples (file name, text extracted from the PDF)
print(data)

# split the extracted data into text chunks using the text_splitter, which splits the text based on the specified number of characters and overlap
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=300, chunk_overlap=40)
text_chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(data)
# print the number of chunks obtained
print("Chunk length: {0}".format(len(text_chunks)))

# Add to VectorDB
vectorstore = SKLearnVectorStore.from_documents(
    documents=text_chunks,
    embedding=NomicEmbeddings(model='nomic-embed-text-v1.5', inference_mode='local')
)

# Create retriever
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(k=3)

# Create a retriever tool, so that an agent can summon the retriever
retriever_tool = create_retriever_tool(retriever, name="retriever",description="A tool for retrieving documents from a file")
#formated_docs = retriever_tool.invoke("battery")

# Equip the llm with the capacity for summoning the tool
tools = [retriever_tool]
llm_with_tools = llm.bind_tools(tools)

#Create a class to store the state of the graph
class State(TypedDict):
    messages: Annotated[list, add_messages]

#Prompt template
rag_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        ("system","You are helpful sales assistant at an online cell phone store."),
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="messages"),
    ]
)

#Chain that passes the prompt to the model with tools
rag_chain = (rag_prompt | llm_with_tools)

#Function that runs the chain
def rag_bot(state: State):
    return {"mesages": [rag_chain.invoke(state["messages"])]}

#This function checks if there is a message. If there is, it checks if 
# the message has a tool_calls. If it has it returns "tools", otherwise
# it returns END.
def route_tools(state: State):
    if isinstance(state, list):
        ai_message = state[-1]
    elif messages := state.get("messages", []):
        ai_message = messages[-1]
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"No messages found in input state to tool_edge: {state}")
    if hasattr(ai_message, "tool_calls") and len(ai_message.tool_calls) > 0:
        return "tools"
    return END


## Define a new graph
graph_builder = StateGraph(state_schema=State)

#Nodes----------------------------------
#Chatbot node
graph_builder.add_node("chatbot",rag_bot)
#Tool node
graph_builder.add_node("tools",tool_node)

#Edges----------------------------------
#Initial edge
graph_builder.add_edge(START, "chatbot")
#Edge directing the tools output to chatbot
graph_builder.add_edge("tools","chatbot")

#Conditional edge connecting chatbot to either tools or END,
# using the route_tools function
graph_builder.add_conditional_edges("chatbot",route_tools,{"tools":"tools", END:END})

memory = MemorySaver()
graph = graph_builder.compile(checkpointer=memory)


# Test
tid1 = uuid.uuid4()
config = {"configurable": {"thread_id": tid1}}
query = "Hi, I'm Bob. Which phone has the best battery?"

input_messages = [query]
for event in graph.stream({"messages": input_messages}, config, stream_mode="values"):
    print(event)

When I run the graph, I get the following error:
InvalidUpdateError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 7
      4 query = "Hi, I'm Bob. Which phone has the best battery?"
      6 input_messages = [query]
----> 7 for event in graph.stream({"messages": input_messages}, config, stream_mode="values"):
      8     print(event)
      9 #output["messages"][-1].pretty_print()

File ~/Documents/LLMs/llmenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langgraph/pregel/__init__.py:1315, in Pregel.stream(self, input, config, stream_mode, output_keys, interrupt_before, interrupt_after, debug, subgraphs)
   1304     # Similarly to Bulk Synchronous Parallel / Pregel model
   1305     # computation proceeds in steps, while there are channel updates
   1306     # channel updates from step N are only visible in step N+1
   1307     # channels are guaranteed to be immutable for the duration of the step,
   1308     # with channel updates applied only at the transition between steps
   1309     while loop.tick(
   1310         input_keys=self.input_channels,
   1311         interrupt_before=interrupt_before_,
   1312         interrupt_after=interrupt_after_,
   1313         manager=run_manager,
   1314     ):
-> 1315         for _ in runner.tick(
   1316             loop.tasks.values(),
   1317             timeout=self.step_timeout,
   1318             retry_policy=self.retry_policy,
   1319             get_waiter=get_waiter,
   1320         ):
   1321             # emit output
   1322             yield from output()
   1323 # emit output

File ~/Documents/LLMs/llmenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langgraph/pregel/runner.py:56, in PregelRunner.tick(self, tasks, reraise, timeout, retry_policy, get_waiter)
     54 t = tasks[0]
     55 try:
---> 56     run_with_retry(t, retry_policy)
     57     self.commit(t, None)
     58 except Exception as exc:

File ~/Documents/LLMs/llmenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langgraph/pregel/retry.py:29, in run_with_retry(task, retry_policy)
     27 task.writes.clear()
     28 # run the task
---> 29 task.proc.invoke(task.input, config)
     30 # if successful, end
     31 break

File ~/Documents/LLMs/llmenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langgraph/utils/runnable.py:412, in RunnableSeq.invoke(self, input, config, **kwargs)
    410             input = context.run(step.invoke, input, config, **kwargs)
    411         else:
--> 412             input = context.run(step.invoke, input, config)
    413 # finish the root run
    414 except BaseException as e:

File ~/Documents/LLMs/llmenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langgraph/utils/runnable.py:176, in RunnableCallable.invoke(self, input, config, **kwargs)
    174     context = copy_context()
    175     context.run(_set_config_context, child_config)
--> 176     ret = context.run(self.func, input, **kwargs)
    177 except BaseException as e:
    178     run_manager.on_chain_error(e)

File ~/Documents/LLMs/llmenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langgraph/pregel/write.py:85, in ChannelWrite._write(self, input, config)
     78 def _write(self, input: Any, config: RunnableConfig) -> None:
     79     writes = [
     80         ChannelWriteEntry(write.channel, input, write.skip_none, write.mapper)
     81         if isinstance(write, ChannelWriteEntry) and write.value is PASSTHROUGH
     82         else write
     83         for write in self.writes
     84     ]
---> 85     self.do_write(
     86         config,
     87         writes,
     88         self.require_at_least_one_of if input is not None else None,
     89     )
     90     return input

File ~/Documents/LLMs/llmenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langgraph/pregel/write.py:138, in ChannelWrite.do_write(config, writes, require_at_least_one_of)
    136 if require_at_least_one_of is not None:
    137     if not {chan for chan, _ in filtered} & set(require_at_least_one_of):
--> 138         raise InvalidUpdateError(
    139             f"Must write to at least one of {require_at_least_one_of}"
    140         )
    141 write: TYPE_SEND = config[CONF][CONFIG_KEY_SEND]
    142 write(sends + filtered)

InvalidUpdateError: Must write to at least one of ['messages']

I saw that Runnable objects receive a Union[dict[str, Any], Any]. I have tested the nodes individually by taking the output of one and using it as the input of the following one, and they don't produce this error.

fix the typo from 'mesages' to 'messages' in your rag_bot function

True, how embarrasing! Thank you Benyamin for your help.
